# Code should determine which value in an array occurs most often, but causes an error when run

Tags: c++, arrays

This code should determine which value in the array occurs most often, but when I try to run it, it causes an error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f(int ptr[], int size) {
  int s = 0;
  int* ptr2 = new int[size];
  for (int y = 0; y <= size - 1; y++) {
    ptr2[y] = 0;
  }
  for (int o = 0; o <= size; o++) {
    for (int os = 0; os < size; o++) {
      if (ptr[o] == ptr[os]) ptr2[o]++;
    }
  }
  int m;
  for (int l = 0; l < size - 1; l++) {
    m = ptr[0];

    if (m < ptr2[l + 1]) {
      s = l + 1;
    }
  }
  return ptr[s];
};

int main() {
  int size;
  cout << "enter number \n";
  cin >> size;
  int* ptr = new int[size];
  for (int l = 0; l <= size - 1; l++) {
    cout << "enter number " << endl;
    cin >> ptr[l];
  }
  cout << f(ptr, size) << endl;
  delete[] ptr;
}
```

Comment: Please try to make your code readable. It is impossible to guess what it originally was. (But your indexing looks very suspicious.)

Comment: i started trying to fix formatting, but it isnt just formatting. Please review your code

Comment: I see a strange mix of `< size`, `<= size-1`, and `<= size`. The conventional "loop over an entire array" boundary is `< size`. Stick to that.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I sometimes fix bad formatting by pasting the code into Compiler Explorer, doing right click followed by "Format Text". For example, here's [this question's code](https://godbolt.org/z/T8G7cT)

Comment: @Blastfurnance thanks, didnt know that. Pretty cool feature. Though here the problem was that code started with `#include #include using namespace std;` no formatter can fix that ;)

Comment: `for (int o = 0; o <= size; o++)` - this loop will go out of bounds of both arrays

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some bugs that need to be fixed

- Do not ever use "using namespace std;"
- Replace `l <= size - 1` with `l < size`
- There are more comparison problems. Fix them all
- At the end of the function you have a `;` Remove that.
- In your function you use `new`, but not `delete`. Please delete your allocated memory.
- The for loop `for (int o = 0; o <= size; o++) {` leads to an out of bounds desaster. Please change `<=` to `<`
- In `for (int os = 0; os < size; o++) {` you have a typo. Please replace `o++` with `os++`

Your software would then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int ptr[], int size) {
    int s = 0;
    int* ptr2 = new int[size];
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        ptr2[y] = 0;
    }
    for (int o = 0; o < size; o++) {
        for (int os = 0; os < size; os++) {
            if (ptr[o] == ptr[os]) ptr2[o]++;
        }
    }
    int m;
    for (int l = 0; l < size - 1; l++) {
        m = ptr[0];

        if (m < ptr2[l + 1]) {
            s = l + 1;
        }
    }
    delete[] ptr2;
    return ptr[s];
};

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cout << "enter number \n";
    std::cin >> size;
    int* ptr = new int[size];
    for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
        std::cout << "enter number " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> ptr[l];
    }
    std::cout << f(ptr, size) << std::endl;
    delete[] ptr;
}
```

If you enable all compiler warnings, then you will already get some hints from clang

Additionally:

- In C++ we do not use raw pointers for owned memory.
- And, of course also not `new` and `delete`
- Also. You should not use C-Style arrays in C++. Always use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.
- Use longer variable names
- Write comments
- Select an indentation style and use it consequently

By the way. With more advance C++ you could also write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Function to get most frequent used number in a vector
int topFrequent(std::vector<int>& numbers) {

    // Count all occurences of numbers
    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counter{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) counter[numbers[i]]++;

    // Waste some memory and sort
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>> heap;
    for (auto x : counter) heap.push(std::make_pair(x.second, x.first));
    
    // Return most frequent number
    return heap.top().second;
}

int main() {
    // Instruct user what to do
    std::cout << "How many numbers do you want to check? Please Enter a number: ";

    // Get count of numbers to read
    if (unsigned int count{}; (std::cin >> count) && (count > 0)) {

        // Read all data
        std::vector<int> data{};
        std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter " << count << " values:\n";
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), count, std::back_inserter(data));

        // Show result
        std::cout << "\n\nMost frequent used number is: " << topFrequent(data) << "\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem with input\n\n";
}
```

To be compiled with C++17